# Setting Gmail up to send emails from Amazon SES SMTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

Very close on this, I'm just missing some small detail.

Here's the error - Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 530 Authentication required

Links I've followed:
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-email-client.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Any ideas would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Setting up gmail to send mail **from** SES?  It isn't clear what you are actually trying to do. Please clarify your objective and exactly how you're trying to accomplish it.  Is there some code involved, somewhere?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you using SES to send or receive emails? And are you sending an email using Gmail or are you expecting to receive an email on Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, solved it.

For clarity, was trying to compose an email in Gmail and then send with new email address that had been earlier set up in AWS SES.

The problem was the MX record, was pointing to the wrong region.

Thanks!!